# How can attribute's code know what type it's applied to?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

```
public class SomeAttr: Attribute
{
    void Method()
    {
        //here I want to know the type this instance of attribute is applied to
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular .NET, it doesn't and can't (unless you tell it manually); sorry. You'll need to include some `typeof(Foo)` in the attribute constructor / properties. If you are talking AOP (PostSharp etc), then all bets are off.

If you mean some of the attributes used by `TypeDescriptor` (`[DisplayName]`, `[TypeConverter]`, etc), then there may be other options - but rather specific and non-trivial to implement.

Comment: Marc, could you give me links where I can see how it's done with AOP?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about PostSharp to answer that; but since it is a rewriter, most things are possible.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the type (using typeof) into the Attribute constructor, e.g,.

```
class SomeAttr : Attribute
{
    private Type _type;

    public SomeAttr(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

    private void Method()
    {
        string s = _type.ToString(); // Example usage of type.
    }
}
```